# read manipulate and write to the db in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am going to read the data by query, manipulate some values and write it back to the db. I use the code below but I get an error.

```
$data = DB::table('users')->get()->toArray();
foreach ($data as $d){
  $d->id = $id+100;
  DB::table('users')->insert($d);
}

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array,
```

but the input is already an array. Do you have a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. let's explain this, what `->toArray()` actually did is converting the whole collection to array not casting the selected records to array so if you `dd($data)` you will find it's an array of objects not array of arrays, so what you need to do is to cast each record in the selected records like so

```
$data = DB::table('users')->get()->map(function ($user) {
    return (array) $user;
})->toArray();
```

as i said

- `->toArray()` - this will convert the whole collection to array
- (array) $user - this will convert the selected record to array

Answer (score 0):

you  can simply use increment function

```
DB::table('users')
->increment('id', 100);
```

more info : [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#increment-and-decrement)